# Limit of $\frac{1}{x(e^{2/x}-1)}$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am trying to compute the limit of $$\frac{1}{x(e^{2/x}-1)}$$ as $x \rightarrow \infty,$ without using l'Hopital, but I am getting nowhere.

I have tried to rewrite it using $ln()$ so that the expression is $ln\left(\frac{1}{x(e^{2/x}-1))} \right) = ln(1) - ln(x(e^{2/x}-1)) = ln(1) - ln(x) + ln(e^{2/x}-1))$, but that didn't help.

I tried changing a variable but didn't know which one, I tried putting $y=e^{1/x}$ so that $x = \frac{1}{ln(y)}$ and so that the whole expression in the limit is $\frac{ln(y)}{y^2-1}$ as $y \rightarrow 1$ but then the denominator is still $0$.

Any advice?

Edit: This is my first calculus course and I haven't started on taylor expansions, derivatives, integrals or anything like that. So I guess I am supposed to solve it using algebra, basically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One may use the standard result
$$
\lim_{u \to 0}\frac{e^u-1}u=1
$$ giving directly
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac1{x(e^{\large \frac2x}-1)}=\frac12\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\large \frac2x}{e^{\large \frac2x}-1}=\frac12 \cdot1=\frac12.
$$

---

Another path. By the Taylor series expansion, as $u \to 0$, one has
$$
e^u=1+u+O(u^2)
$$ giving, as $x \to \infty$,
$$
e^{\large \frac2x}=1+\frac2x+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)
$$$$
x(e^{\large \frac2x}-1)=2+O\left(\frac1{x}\right)
$$ and, as $x \to \infty$,
$$
\frac1{x(e^{\large \frac2x}-1)}=\frac1{2+O\left(\frac1{x}\right)} \to \frac12.
$$

---

Comment: Oh, we haven't begun with taylor expansions yet. I should have mentioned that, but seeing I don't know anything about them yet I didn't know that was an option. Will edit!

Comment: @vinterrr Ok, see my edit. Is it clear for you now?

Comment: Yes, very clear, thank you! And I'm sorry you had to waste time writing it the Taylor way, although it is nice to see that there are several ways to compute such a limit, so I will come back and look at it again once I learn about Taylor expansions.

Comment: @vinterrr You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

How about $y=1/x$

$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{y}{e^{2y}-1}$$

Then using the Taylor expansion of $\exp{2y}$

$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{y}{-1+1+2y+2y^2+\cdots}=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{y}{2y}=\frac 12$$

Alternatively, without Taylor:
$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{y}{e^{2y}-1}$$

Take $u=2y$:
$$\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac 12 \frac{u}{e^{u}-1}$$

Set $u=\ln(t)$:
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 1}\frac 12 \frac{\ln t}{t-1}$$
Using the definition of $\ln(x)$
$$L=\lim_{t\rightarrow 1}\frac{\ln(t)}{t-1}=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(t+1)}{t}=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\int_0^t \frac 1t\frac{dr}{1+r}$$
Put: $r=ts \implies dr=tds$ then:
$$L=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\int_0^1 \frac{ds}{1+ts}=\int_0^1ds=1$$
P.S.: I know I've used an integral, but can't we apply a simple one like this?